# What's the deference between product catalog and category in Ofbiz?

Tags: categories, catalog, ofbiz

What's the deference between product catalog and category in Ofbiz ?

I think all of them is a group or set of product that have one or more common characteristics. But in Ofbiz's using one Catalog have many Category ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are similar, but catalog contains a list of categories with different purposes: home page categories, search categories, etc.
http://ofbiz.135035.n4.nabble.com/Product-Category-and-Catalog-td4636208.html

Comment: Lbryam: thanks, I understood right now. I will read carefully.